# Extract domain from link

Tags: php

I'm looking for a bullet proof way to extract domain (with tld) from any given link - an eqivalent of `dirname($path)` let's call it domainname($link).

```
echo domainname("http://example.com/index.html?a=123%1231");
```

should print "example.com"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) return value has a `host` key.

Answer (score 8):

```
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

More info: http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: component parameter was added in php 5.1.2