# Match Array Values to URL String

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$blacklist = array("asdf.com", "fun.com", "url.com");
```

I have an input string:

```
$input = "http://asdf.com/asdf/1234/";
```

I am trying to see if string $input matches any values in $blacklist.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a decent use for `parse_url()`:

```
<?php
    $blacklist = array("asdf.com", "fun.com", "url.com");
    $input = "http://asdf.com/asdf/1234/";

    $url = parse_url($input);

    echo (in_array($url['host'], $blacklist) ? '(FAIL)' : '(PASS)') . $url ['host'];
?>
```

**Output:**

```
(FAIL)asdf.com
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be (but I didn't measure performance):

```
$san = preg_replace($blacklist, '', $input);

if($san !== $input) {
    //contained something from the blacklist
}
```

If the input does not contain any string from the backlist, the string will be returned unchanged.

An other, maybe better suited and definitely more efficient approach could be to [extract the host part from the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630166/extract-domain-from-link) and create the blacklist as associative array:

```
$blacklist = array(
      "asdf.com" => true,
      "fun.com" => true, 
      "url.com" => true
);
```

Then testing would be `O(1)` with:

```
if($blacklist[$host]) {
    //contained something from the blacklist
}
```

Comment: Didn't you know how much I hate down votes without a comment? Fear my wrath!

Comment: @KingCrunch: Yes the first one is more or less a hack. Lets say I thought about a creative way ;) Regarding the second: Arrays in PHP are ordered maps, they are neither lists nor sets. `in_array` will always be slower as it has to perform a linear search. This is not relevant for small arrays of course...

Comment: Arrays are implemented as hash maps, not only as maps. However, they can be treated differently in different situations. So for example you can use an array as a set, list, stack, queue, or whatever. Its just about naming here and has not much to do with the implemenation. And about `in_array()`: Clean code > micro optimization

Comment: @KingCrunch: I'm just repeating what is written in the documentation (normally hash maps cannot guarantee order, but PHP arrays do). I meant ordered hash maps. Of course they can be used as (nearly) anything else, that's why arrays are so great :) Imo clean code is subjective to some degree. I personally find a lookup map much cleaner as a linear search. But anyway, now I know at least what you didn't like. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using foreach is probably the best solution for what you're trying to achieve.

```
$blacklist = array("/asdf\.com/", "/fun\.com/", "/url\.com/");

foreach($blacklist as $bl) {
  if (preg_match($bl, $input)){return true;}
}
```

Comment: what are you `return`'ing to?

Comment: @jnpcl If he's using a function check. Of course it's optional. Pretty obvious...

Comment: It may be obvious to those of us offering answers, but it may not be obvious to the OP. Your answer does not work "as is", and though it is a viable solution, it requires extra code that the OP may not realize he needs to add.

Answer (score 0):

in_array is of no use, as it searches for the exact string.

You have to loop through the array, and search for it

```
foreach($str in $blacklist)
{
   if( stristr($input, $str ) )
    {
         //found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$blacklist = array("asdf.com", "fun.com", "url.com");
$input = "http://asdf.com/asdf/1234/";
if (in_array(parse_url($input,PHP_URL_HOST),$blacklist))
  {
  // The website is in the blacklist.
  }
```

Comment: Which is essentially the same as given in @jnpcl's answer. There is no need to duplicate answers... -1.